# Android 5.0 - adb screencap by shell command

Tags: android, shell, adb

I want to do a screenshot on device executed by the adb shell. On Android 5.0 shall some commands public, means without to need root permissions.

When I try to execute that command, I am not getting a permission failure, instead I get this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/system/bin/adb, shell, screencap, -p, /sdcard/screencap.png] Working Directory: /system/bin/adb Environment: null
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:246)
    at MyActivity.executeCommand(MyActivity.java:181)
    at MyActivity$2.run(MyActivity.java:170)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    System.err﹕ Caused by: java.io.IOException: Not a directory
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
    ... 5 more
```

Why is my Environment null ?

Here is my code:

```
public static boolean executeCommand(String command, String path) {

    System.out.println("executing command: " + command);
    Process p;
    try {

        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, new File(path));
        p.waitFor();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

        if (output.length() > 0) {

            System.out.println("Result: " + output.toString());
        }

        if (p.getErrorStream().available() > 0) {

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            output = new StringBuilder("");
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                output.append(line + "\n");
            }
            if (output.length() > 0) {

                System.out.println("Result: " + output.toString());
            }
            return false;
        }
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(p.getOutputStream());
        printStream.println();
        printStream.flush();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the execution:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        String screencapCmd = "/system/bin/adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/" + "screencap.png";
        boolean screenCapTaken = executeCommand(screencapCmd, "/system/bin/adb");
    }
});
t.start();
```

Comment: When I just use following command, it is creating that file, but its empty.

screencap -p /sdcard/screencap.png

Comment: Nice, I get a -1 without a comment !?! So please comment or leave !

Comment: Why not just create a shell script to take the screenshot? Example: http://pastebin.com/K6Gdcdvh

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Technically there should be a security exception.